# Finding error in Magento checkout process

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento, quote

I'm currently working on a Magento site and we're having some issues with the checkout process. We're using the Advanced Custom Options plugin and have some strange issues where we can't proceed to checkout with any item that has dependent required options. It sucessfully adds to cart but failure is triggered and onepage redirects back to the shopping cart. I've narrowed it down to `$quote->getHasError()` returning 1 in OnepageController.php line 169. Does anyone know how to return what that error is. I'm not overly familiar with Zend and have tried `$quote->getError()` but that returns nothing. Any help would be appriciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
```

Maintain this two lines to print errors in zend framework

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Daya suggestions you can use XDebug, it will save you a lot of time